# atomicAdd() for double on GPU

Tags: cuda, atomic

I am doing a project on GPU, and I have to use atomicAdd() for double, because the cuda does not support it for double, so I use the code below, which is NVIDIA provide.

```
__device__ double atomicAdd(double* address, double val)
{
    unsigned long long int* address_as_ull =
                                          (unsigned long long int*)address;
    unsigned long long int old = *address_as_ull, assumed;
    do {
        assumed = old;
        old = atomicCAS(address_as_ull, assumed, 
                        __double_as_longlong(val + 
                        __longlong_as_double(assumed)));
    } while (assumed != old);
    return __longlong_as_double(old);
}
```

Now I want to know why the implement require a loop, while (assumed!=old)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically because the implementation requires a load, which can't be performed atomically. The compare-and-swap operation is an atomic version of

```
(*address == assumed) ? (assumed + val) : *address
```

There is no guarantee the the value at `*address` won't change between the cycle that the value is loaded from `*address` and the cycle that the `atomicCAS` call is used to store the updated value. If that happens, the value at `*address` won't be updated. Therefore the loop ensures that the two operations are repeated until there is no change of the value at `*address` between the read and the compare-and-swap operation, which implies that the update took place.

Comment: thanks!you mean the load operation ,assumed=old,is not atomic,so the the atomic function old=atomicCAS(address_as_ull,assumed,__double_as_long(val+__longlong_as_double(assumed))) is launched, the value of old may be changed, and the add() should do again, guarantee current value to be added either.

Comment: No. `old` is a thread local variable. Its value doesn't change unless the local thread changes it. The only value which can change, outside of the threads control is `*address`. When it is changed by another thread during the operation, the `atomicCAS` call must be repeated, otherwise the update doesn't occur.

Comment: I got it,the function of loop guarantee that current value of change for *address_as_ull is done by current thread.